# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a problem with this query:

```
SELECT @dateforaftersixmonth=U_PYMON FROM [@CCS_PYRUNPERIODS] 
    WHERE @STRTEMP_DATE between U_BEGDA and U_ENDDA
```

`@STRTEMP_DATE` is a datetime variable and `@dateforaftersixmonth` is a string. `U_BEGDA` and `U_ENDDA` are datetime fields and `U_PYMON` is varchar.

But when I execute this query I get:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

And when I execute this query separately I can't find any error and I got the answer. Here `@STRTEMP_DATE` comes is `'Mar  1 2013 12:00AM'`.

Comment: You really have a table named `[@CCS_PYRUNPERIODS]`?

Comment: ya this is a table created in sap b1

Comment: FYI I'm closing at Too Localized since the root of the problem is you don't actually know what your datatypes are...

Comment: I would like to point out that your problems are primarily programming problems and do not generally (so far) require the knowledge of database administrators, per-se, but just the knowledge of programmers in general who are familiar with SQL and the various SQL variants (TSQL, PL-SQL, etc). You would do better to ask questions on [so] when your questions are basic SQL and then let them be migrated here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @STRTEMP_DATE is a datetime variable and @dateforaftersixmonth is a
>   string. U_BEGDA and U_ENDDA are datetime fields and U_PYMON is
>   varchar.

The error indicates that there is an implicit conversion from string to date/time. As you stated the variables and fields here, there is no implicit conversion. Since I trust the error message more than I trust you, I must conclude that you did not stated the variable and column types correctly and at least one of the following is true:

- @STRTEMP_DATE is a string and U_BEGDA  or U_ENDDA is a date/time column
- @STRTEMP_DATE is a date/time variable and U_ENDDA is a string column
- @dateforaftersixmonth is a string and U_PYMON is a date/time columns
- @dateforaftersixmonth is a date/time and U_PYMON is a string column

One of the above must be true for the conversion to occur and for the erorr message to appear. My money is on the `@dateforaftersixmonth` being a datetime and `U_PYMON` being a string (varchar or nvarchar). This also explains the aparent randomness of the error: it occurs only when you scan a range that contains values that cannot be converted.

Depending on which of the above cases happens, the solution is to appropiately modify the parameter/variable or the column to be of type datetime when storing dates/times.

Comment: I think the implicit conversion problem comes from calling the procedure, e.g. `EXEC dbo.foo 'Mar 1 2013 12:00AM';` - I think this can be happening and the OP being correct about their variables and data types.

Comment: (e.g. if the session language is not US English.)

Comment: thank u .its problem due to datatype mismatching...
@dateforaftersixmonth is a date/time and U_PYMON is a string column  is the problem

Comment: @Sivajith than why did you say `@dateforaftersixmonth is a string`?

Comment: i declared @dateforaftersixmonth as datetime variable and u_pymon is actually string...

Answer (score 1):

Why are you passing a string like `'Mar 1 2013 12:00 AM'`? Try using an unambiguous and non-regional format such as `'20130301'`. Surely you can use `.Format()` in your client application to prepare the string in the right way. For some background on this please read:

- https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries

And also please stop using `BETWEEN` for date range queries. See this for why:

- https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: thank you all...'Mar 1 2013 12:00 AM' is the date format getting from database table...

Comment: @Sivajith no it's not. If the column is a datetime column, that's *not* how it's stored, that's just how Management Studio might present it to you when you use PRINT or something along those lines.

Comment: hi, ya when i use the print statement i got that

i always have trouble with the datetime format and this time i can't catch the error..
i got the answer...and how can i close this question